# What is the most performant way to slice a datetime in a multi-index?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, multi-index

What is the most 'performant' way to filter a DataFrame by time if the DataFrame has a multi-index containing a datetime index?

For example, how to filter for business hours only in a datetime index which is contained in a multi-index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to filter for business hours only in a datetime index which is contained in a multi-index.

```
df.index.get_level_values(1).hour.isin([9,10,11,13,14,15,16])
```

That's just one example--filter the second level of a MultiIndex which is a datetime column and get a boolean mask which is True wherever the hour is 9 to 5 excluding lunch break.

Need more precision?

```
dt = df.index.get_level_values(1)
minutes = dt.hour * 60 + dt.minute
minutes.between(8*60+15, 17*60+45)
```

That's 8:15 to 17:45.

Siesta?

```
minutes.between(9*60+30, 15*60) | minutes.between(17*60+30, 20*60)
```